# VBA - Skipping rows and overwriting the row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to programming but have been trying for a while to learn. I am running into an issue where I am trying to pull stock prices out of Yahoo Finance, but I need it to skip rows 4, 6, 20, 34, 41. These cells are also blank in the C column. I have tried using an if statement where
    if ws.Range("K6, K20, K34, K41").value = "" Then exit sub
But this made it so the whole program did not run.
Also, when it does run, it will create a new column where the previous "K" Column was, instead of just overwriting K, which is what I'm trying to do.

Thank you for your help! Sorry if this question seemed confusing, I'm here to clarify any questions! :)

```
Sub BtnRefresh()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim URL As String    
Dim Symbol As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Last As Integer
Set ws = Worksheets("Current Portfolio")



Last = ws.Range("C100").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Last
    Symbol = Symbol & ws.Range("C" & i).Value & "+"

Next i


URL = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbol & "&f=l1"

Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
    Destination:=Range("K5"))
        qt.BackgroundQuery = True
        qt.SaveData = True

        qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        qt.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip them, or you can change the blanks to zeros such as:

```
Last = ws.Range("C100").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Last
     If Cells(i,3).Value=""
         Cells(i,3).Value="0"
         Else
         End If

    Symbol = Symbol & ws.Range("C" & i).Value & "+"

Next i

Range("C4,C6,C20,C34,C41").ClearContents
```

This lets you just keep your Symbol formula as is.

Do those blank cells in C need to stay blank?  If so, I can re-work this.

Edit: Re-worked to make sure those cells have the content deleted.  If you don't need that, just don't add the line to .ClearContents.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response, this one sort of worked, but now I am getting "N/A" being pasted inside 'K4:K7' as well as K9, K23, K37

Comment: Hey! This worked after I made 'For i = **5** To Last' Thank you!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get rid of the N/A that is appearing in the cells? I tried 'Cells.Replace "N/A", ""' but now everytime I run the Macro the entire worksheet gets high lighted. Thanks!

Comment: That means there's an error in the calculation.  in terms of formulas, you can use iferror(formula,value), where the value you want to have output when there is an error is either "" or "0".  You would need to see where the error occurs in column K's formula to make sure you're correcting the correct thing.

Answer (score 0):

For an easy to maintain exclusion list based approach, replace your `FOR.. NEXT` loop with:

```
exclude = "4/6/20/34"

For i = 1 To Last
    If InStr(1, "/" & exclude & "/", "/" & Trim(Str(i)) & "/") = 0 Then Symbol = Symbol & ws.Range("C" & i).Value & "+"
Next
```

As for the column K problem, if you can't just issue a `Refresh` as the data picked up by the loop might change, then how about just clearing the table with:

```
Range("K:K").ClearContents ' or ("K:N") or whatever depending on width of the table?
```

Comment: Hey CLR, thank your for your response, but it still is not skipping the cells.